# Sending array of JSON through requestJS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, express, request

I'm sending an array of JSON objects through a post request using request js

Here is the code:

```
app.post('/booking2/:airline', function(req, res){
var airline = req.params.airline;
var paymentToken = req.body.paymentToken;
var body = req.body;
var file = require("./URLs.json")
var url = file[airline];
var passengerDetails = [];
var passenger = {
    'firstName': body.firstName,
    'lastName': body.lastName,
    'passportNum': body.passportNum,
    'passportExpiryDate': body.passportExpiryDate,
    'nationality': body.nationality,
    'email': body.email
}
passengerDetails.push(passenger);

var options = {
    url: 'http://' + url + '/booking',
    json: true,
    headers: {
    'x-access-token': "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIiLCJpYXQiOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MWUrOTQsImF1ZCI6IiIsInN1YiI6IiJ9.TlE9xzrGaxsAkfCnLo737-dnnot_DORFEFLWKC40iM0",
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    form:{  
        'paymentToken': body.paymentToken,
        'outgoingFlightId': body.outgoingFlightId,
        'returnFlightId': body.returnFlightId,
        'cost': body.cost,
        'class': body.class,
        'passengerDetails': passengerDetails
    }
};

  function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body)
    res.end(JSON.stringify(body))
  }else{
   // res.end(error);
  }
}

console.log(options.form)
request.post(options, callback);



});
```

When I print the form on the server, this shows up in the terminal:

```
 { paymentToken: 'tok_1874nlKDBqzT4NOb5oS8cW5o',
 outgoingFlightId: '570fb24c3055c16518febb10',
 returnFlightId: '',
 cost: '2000',
 class: 'economy',
 passengerDetails: 
  [ { firstName: 'n',
   lastName: 'n',
   passportNum: 'n',
   passportExpiryDate: 'n',
   nationality: 'n',
   email: 'n' } ] }
```

However, on the other server, the data ends up looking like this:

```
{
"outgoingFlightId" : "570fb24c3055c16518febb10",
"returnFlightId" : "",
"class" : "Economy",
"passengerDetails[0][firstName]" : "n",
"passengerDetails[0][lastName]" : "n",
"passengerDetails[0][passportNum]" : "n",
"passengerDetails[0][passportExpiryDate]" : "n",
"passengerDetails[0][nationality]" : "n",
"passengerDetails[0][email]" : "n",
"refNum" : "HTMtTuG",
"_id" : ObjectId("5728b447cabedd6e174e0ff8")
}
```

I need the array to be sent as it is to the other server. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try to change `form:{...}` to `data:{...}`

Comment: I did that, the data inside it never reached the other server

Comment: Sorry my bad. Then use multipart. Have a look in docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartrelated